# Predicting results of a calorimetry experiment

Tags: thermodynamics

Hypothetically, if one had to mix 1 kilogram of ice at 0 degrees centigrade with 1 kilogram of steam at 100 degrees centigrade, what would be the resultant mixture?

##### Assumption 1

I was trying to predict this by using basic calorimetry, and I began by assuming that both, the ice would melt to water at 0 degrees, and the steam would condense to water at 100 degrees, and in the end, the temperature would be somewhat between 0 and 100 degrees centigrade, and the final mixture would be water only.

However, my assumption was incorrect, because the resultant temperature came to 290 degrees centigrade (which is surely not possible).

##### Assumption 2

I then assumed that all the steam condenses, but the ice doesn't fully melt, forming a final mixture of water and ice both.
But once again, I got a really weird answer, with the final temperature being once more, way above 100 degrees.

##### Assumption 3

I assumed then that all the ice melts, but the steam doesn't fully condense, forming a final mixture of steam and water both.
Surprisingly, this third assumption was correct, because my answer came up to 665 grams of steam, and 1.335 kilograms of water at 100 degrees exactly.

##### Question

Is there any way to avoid these meaningless assumptions from the start, and predict the final state of the mixture before calculating?

Comment: Did you mean that the steam is initially at 100°C?

Comment: yea sorry, I meant 100°C

Comment: If you compare the heat of fusion with the heat of vaporization/condensation, this should give you a better idea of which assumption to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the energy required to melt all the ice to the energy released if all the steam condensed.

If the energy liberated when all steam turns to water is **greater** than energy required to melt the ice, then all the ice will melt.
If the energy liberated when all steam turns to water is **less** than energy required to melt the ice, then all the steam will condense.

Having decided whether all the ice will melt or all the steam condenses evaluate,
the energy change for the melted ice water at $0$ degrees to become water at $100$ degrees and compare the value with the energy available from condensing the steam that is left after melting the ice,
or
the energy change for the condensed steam water at $100$ degrees to become water at $0$ degrees and compare the value with the energy available from melting the ice that is left after condensing the steam.